# Error importing stellar-sdk into angular 8 project

Tags: typescript, angular8, eventsource

We're trying to develop an app to interact with Horizon Stellar Server. We are new in the area and we¿re trying to Angular 8 and Ionic 4, but we havent been able to import the js-stellar-sdk successfully. I created a brand new app to test but it fails to compile.

Tried this: 
https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/1280/using-stellar-sdk-in-angular?rq=1
But I get StellarSdk is not defined and Server is not a constructor/function (when I comment the declaration).

Also found this:
https://github.com/stellar/js-stellar-base/issues/128
but they said its already fixed:
https://github.com/stellar/js-stellar-base/issues/128#issuecomment-474474028
Wanted to try this: 
https://github.com/stellar/js-stellar-base/issues/128#issuecomment-391374590
But it seems its no longer created in Angular 8 (dont know if I have to created it).

this is my app.component.ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Server } from 'stellar-sdk';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'example';
  server: any;

  ngOnInit(): void{
    this.server = new Server('https://horizon.stellar.org');
  }  
}
```

I get the following error:

ERROR in ./node_modules/eventsource/lib/eventsource.js                                                                  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\Rafael Cisneros\Desktop\Work\Ionic\example\node_modules\eventsource\lib'                                                                                                             ERROR in ./node_modules/eventsource/lib/eventsource.js                                                                  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'C:\Users\Rafael Cisneros\Desktop\Work\Ionic\example\node_modules\eventsource\lib'

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve the same problem.
It is related to the file **eventsource.js** in this path: **"\node_modules\stellar-sdk\node_modules\eventsource\lib"**
Open the file and change these:

```
var https = require('https')
var http = require('http')
```

to these:

```
var https = require('@angular/common/http')
var http = require('@angular/common/http')
```

Also if it is still not working consider to change

```
import { Server } from 'stellar-sdk';
```

to this for example:

```
import * as StellarSDK from 'stellar-sdk';
```

Comment: Hey @Raskolnikov ! Can we chat about this?! https://twitter.com/BenRacicot